# Java Set exception on dupe

Tags: java, collections, set

I'm looking for an **existing** Java Set implementation that throws an exception when the [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add%28E%29) method is called with an object that is already in the set. Does anyone know if one exists in a reasonably well-known library?

Edit: There seems to be a lot of confusion about the question. I'm not asking how to implement the set interface. I need to provide a short snippet of code to a vendor w/o sending them a library with a custom collection that I have created. They will have the commonly used libraries available to them (as I know they have been set up with Maven).

Comment: build your own collection and install it into some public maven repository and give the vendor the dependency so that can put it some pom.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The spec allows `.add()` to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` "if some property of the specified element prevents it from being added to this set".  Seems just as reasonable an expectation as `ImmutableSet.add()` throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: @A4L I can't. Corporate policies often don't leave room for logic.

Comment: Your corporate policy won't let you write a <50 line class, but it will let you add a whole new library to your classpath?  What if I just bundle my answer up into a Jar for you?

Comment: @dimo414: I disagree with your interpretation of the doc associated with `IllegalArgumentException`.  In particular, the `Set.add` doc states: "If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set unchanged and returns false."

Comment: @LouisWasserman fair point, but it goes on to say "The stipulation above does not imply that sets must accept all elements; sets may refuse to add any particular element ... and throw an exception".  I would agree it would be in violation of the spec for the set to be *modified* in any way if it already contains the passed element, but as I read it, raising a documented exception is permissible.

Comment: @dimo414: I tend to interpret that clause as saying that there may be some condition on the _element_ required to add it to the set, but I think allowing that condition to depend on the set is a stretch.  For example, a `TreeSet` might reject an element that does not implement `Comparable`, but that has nothing to do with the state of the `Set`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Interesting. Do you hold the same opinion of Collection.add?

Comment: @smp7d: That throwing an exception should indicate something wrong with the element, independent of the state of the collection?  I lean towards yes.

Comment: The "sets may refuse to add any particular element" line, in particular, seems to indicate that it must be the _element_ that's being rejected, not the element-and-collection.  I could buy an argument that `Collection.add` could throw an `IllegalStateException` (`State`, not `Argument`!) in this scenario, but `Set.add`'s spec doesn't appear to allow `IllegalStateException`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class UniqueSet<E> extends HashSet<E> implements Set<E> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UniqueSet() {
    }

    public UniqueSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    public UniqueSet(int initialCapacity) {
        super(initialCapacity);
    }

    public UniqueSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor) {
        super(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        if (super.contains(e))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already in set!");
        return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extending `HashSet`, you'd do better to define a wrapper class that holds a set and modifies it's behavior, per Effective Java #16.

```
import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class FailFastSet<T> extends AbstractSet<T> {
    private final Set<T> backer;

    public FailFastSet() {
        this(new HashSet<T>());
    }

    public FailFastSet(Set<T> set) {
        backer = set;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T e) {
        if (backer.contains(e))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Cannot add "+e+" - equivalent object already exists.");
        return backer.add(e);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return backer.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return backer.size();
    }
}
```